# C# Linq groupby method syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code

```
 var myList = new List<int>() {10, 10, 10, 9, 15};

 var groupedMyList = myList.GroupBy(i => i).ToList();

 var hasFourOfSameValue = groupedMyList.Select(g => g.Count() == 4).Any();
```

The issue is that hasFour comes back as true. I expect it to be false as there is maximum three ints with the same value in the list? (I suspect I go wrong in the groupby call but I can't figure out how to change it).

**Question preamble: I want to use LINQ method syntax not LINQ query syntax.**

Comment: you are counting the "False" booleans...

Comment: Thanks all for helping me out. I shortened the query now and see that in Linqpad it indeed returns list with three false booleans.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression `groupedMyList.Select(g => g.Count() == 4)` returns `{ false, false, false }`. And calling any on a non-empty sequence is true. You want:

```
var hasFourOfSameValue = groupedMyList.Any(g => g.Count() == 4);
```

Comment: Technically it returns `{false, false, false}`. But you are correct on your conclusion.

Answer (score 8):

You want:

```
var hasFourOfSameValue = groupedMyList.Any(grp => grp.Count() == 4);
```

`Any()` returns true if the input sequence contains any elements.